# in-App-Purchase-Binary Rejected due to application crash in iOS7

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode5

I have uploaded app on appstore.its working fine on io6 but when I  uploaded on apple store its rejected due to application crash in iOS7.When I am run it on xcode 4.5 its working fine and I got purchase alertview message but I could not get it on xcode5 and ios7.here is my  source code.

```
- (IBAction)buy {
          activityIndicator.hidden = NO;

          SKMutablePayment *payment = [[[SKMutablePayment alloc] init] autorelease];
         payment.productIdentifier = @"com.test.app.V3";
         [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

        if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) {
            NSLog(@"Parental-controls are disabled");

            SKProductsRequest *productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]           initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:@"com.test.app.V3"]];
            productsRequest.delegate = self;
            [productsRequest start];
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Parental-controls are enabled");
        }
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
    }

    -(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
        SKProduct *validProduct = nil;
        int count = [response.products count];
        if (count > 0) {
            validProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];

        }
        else if (!validProduct) {
            NSLog(@"No Products Available");
        }
    }

    - (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
        for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
            switch (transaction.transactionState) {

                case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
                    //// Stuff Here ////

                    break;

                case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:

                    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                    //// Stuff Here ////

                    activityIndicator.hidden = YES;

                    int coins1 = [money.text intValue];
                    coins1 += 1500;
                    money.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.00", coins1];

                    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasBalance"];
                    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:money.text forKey:@"Balance"];

                    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"ThankYou"];

                    [self exitIAP];

                    break;

                case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                    break;

                case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                    if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {
                        NSLog(@"An Error Encountered");
                    }
                    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                    //// Stuff Here ////

                    activityIndicator.hidden = YES;
                    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"StopThankYou"];

                    [self exitIAP];

                    break;
            }
        }
           }

      - (void)exitIAP {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self];
      }
  appreciate for any kind of help.
  thanks in advance

   crash report 
   Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
   Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
  Triggered by Thread:  0

 Last Exception Backtrace:

   Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
   Thread 0 Crashed:
   0   libsystem_kernel.dylib           0x3a13d1fc __pthread_kill + 8
   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x3a1a6a2e pthread_kill + 54
   2   libsystem_c.dylib                0x3a0edff8 abort + 72
   3   libc++abi.dylib                  0x3941ccd2 abort_message + 70
   4   libc++abi.dylib                  0x394356e0 default_terminate_handler() + 248
   5   libobjc.A.dylib                  0x39b7e91e _objc_terminate() + 190
   6   libc++abi.dylib                  0x394331c4 std::__terminate(void (*)()) +  
    7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x39432a18 __cxa_throw + 112
   8   libobjc.A.dylib                  0x39b7e77e objc_exception_throw + 246
   9   CoreFoundation                   0x2f30b8e2 -[NSObject(NSObject)               
   10  CoreFoundation                   0x2f30a1c6 ___forwarding___ + 702
   11  CoreFoundation                   0x2f2594d4 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 20
   12  DubstepSlots                     0x0017cdce 0x90000 + 970190
   13  StoreKit                         0x31a0cdc8 __NotifyObserverAboutChanges     
   14  CoreFoundation                   0x2f23b656 CFArrayApplyFunction + 34
   15  StoreKit                         0x31a0cd64 -[SKPaymentQueue     _no     
  16  StoreKit                          0x31a0d646 -[SKPaymentQueue   
 17  StoreKit                       0x31a0dd1c -[SKPaymentQueue 
  18  StoreKit                          0x31a0d80a __45-[SKPaymentQueue   
  19  libdispatch.dylib                 0x3a061d18   
   20  libdispatch.dylib                0x3a061d04 _dispatch_client_callout + 20

  22  CoreFoundation                    0x2f2d2814 
    23  CoreFoundation                  0x2f2d10e8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1296
   24  CoreFoundation                   0x2f23bc22 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
  25  CoreFoundation                    0x2f23ba06 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
  26  GraphicsServices                  0x33f3c27e GSEventRunModal + 134
    27  UIKit                           0x31adf044 UIApplicationMain + 1132
   28  DubstepSlots                     0x000a2aaa 0x90000 + 76458
  29  DubstepSlots                      0x00092674 0x90000 + 9844

    Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
    Thread 1:
   0   libsystem_kernel.dylib           0x3a12a83c kevent64 + 24
   1   libdispatch.dylib                0x3a06b210 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 228
   2   libdispatch.dylib                0x3a06af96         

 Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a13dc7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
  1   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x3a1a3dc6 _pthread_wqthread + 306
  2   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x3a1a3c80 start_wqthread + 4

  Thread 3 name:  WebThread
   Thread 3:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x3a12aa8c mach_msg_trap + 20
   1   libsystem_kernel.dylib           0x3a12a888 mach_msg + 44
  2   CoreFoundation                    0x2f2d27be __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort +       
  3   CoreFoundation                    0x2f2d0ee4 __CFRunLoopRun + 780
  4   CoreFoundation                    0x2f23bc22 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
 5   CoreFoundation                 0x2f23ba06 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
  6   WebCore                           0x3742b266 RunWebThread(void*) + 414
  7   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x3a1a5c1a _pthread_body + 138
  8   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x3a1a5b8a _pthread_start + 98
  9   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x3a1a3c8c thread_start + 4

 Thread 4 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.low-priority
Thread 4:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x3a12aadc semaphore_wait_trap + 8
 1   libdispatch.dylib              0x3a069428 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 172
 2   CFNetwork                      0x2eecc6e0 CFURLConnectionSendSynchronousRequest  + 264
  3   Foundation                        0x2fc947ae +[NSURLConnection  
4   Foundation                      0x2fc648c6 -[NSData(NSData)      
5   Foundation                      0x2fc647f6 +[NSData(NSData)   
6   DubstepSlots                    0x000f5ea0 0x90000 + 417440
7   DubstepSlots                    0x000f5d4e 0x90000 + 417102
 8   libdispatch.dylib              0x3a061d18 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
 9   libdispatch.dylib              0x3a068d6c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 216
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x3a068f54 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 52
```

11  libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x3a1a3dbc _pthread_wqthread + 296
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a1a3c80 start_wqthread + 4

Comment: Please add a symbolized crash report.

Answer (score 0):

As rckeones says, it will be difficult to track this down without a symbolicated crash report, but given the information we have, these lines intrigue me:

```
12  DubstepSlots                     0x0017cdce 0x90000 + 970190
13  StoreKit                         0x31a0cdc8 __NotifyObserverAboutChanges     
14  CoreFoundation                   0x2f23b656 CFArrayApplyFunction + 34
15  StoreKit                         0x31a0cd64 -[SKPaymentQueue     _no
```

It implies to me that the SKPaymentQueue is calling out to its observers (one being something in your DubstepSlots project), in which it is crashing.

Looking at your code, you are adding this class as an observer:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
```

That method has the signature

```
- (void)addTransactionObserver:(id<SKPaymentTransactionObserver>)observer
```

Which means that your `self` object must conform to the SKPaymentTransactionObserver protocol. Luckily, you have the required method `- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions;` in your code. I'm pretty sure that this is the method where it is crashing. But if you set a breakpoint at the beginning of this method and step through, I'm sure you'll find out what is wrong.

I don't know for sure, but it seems like the lines

```
8   libobjc.A.dylib                  0x39b7e77e objc_exception_throw + 246
9   CoreFoundation                   0x2f30b8e2 -[NSObject(NSObject)
```

indicate that you might be calling a method that does not exist on an object in that method.

Without the symbolicated report, it is hard to judge what exactly is going wrong (we don't even know what line its crashing on!) That should at least get you started in finding where things are going wrong.

Comment: hey I have already implement   - (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions this method.still getting issue although I have made two version of this app.first was approved in ios6 but after ios7 lunched i have uploaded second version and its rejected

Comment: I understand that you have implemented it. And I'm pretty sure it's being called. I think the crash is happening _inside_ that method. Put a breakpoint in it and walk through the function as it is called on iOS 7, and I'll bet you'll find where (and why) it crashes.

Comment: I have debug also but its return on 
if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {
                        NSLog(@"An Error Encountered");
 } in this method without any crash in in xcode file so I could not understand what's exactly issue is

Comment: Sorry, I dont know what you mean that it returns there... There is clearly code after that, so it should continue. Try logging out the values to see what they really are

Comment: I mean its reutrn SKTransaction fail in following line
    case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                    if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {
                        NSLog(@"An Error Encountered");

Comment: So when you run it on iOS 7, it does not crash, but goes to the case with SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed? Or does it crash for you on iOS 7? Does it crash every time? The crashlog that you provided shows very little helpful information (provide a symbolicated one!), but seems to indicate that it is crashing_somewhere_ in that method.

Comment: its not crashing in xcode and I have also installed on my device its not crashing but I have submited two in appstore and its rejected two time with same issue.when I am debug in xcode its no crashing anywhere but retun transaction fail in xcode5

Comment: Try it on iOS 7 with a release build and see if you can reproduce it. Keep the dsym files too, so you can symbolicate the crash logs and find out what line its actually crashing on.

Comment: hey I have debug and I got bellow user
0x15b820:  cmp    r0, #1
0x15b822:  bne.w  0x15bd82                  ; -[ADCIAPListener paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:] + 2050 at ADCIAPListener.m:123
0x15b826:  ldr    r1, [sp, #72]
0x15b828:  mov    r0, r8
0x15b82a:  str    r4, [sp, #188]
0x15b82c:  blx    0x1b1dc4                  ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x15b830:  mov    r7, r7
0x15b832:  blx    0x1b1de0                  ; symbol stub for: objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue

Comment: I could not find it where it exact issue,I have debug but I could not find in specific method or viewcontroller

Comment: I'm sorry, do you not know how to read stack traces? This line `-[ADCIAPListener paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:] + 2050 at ADCIAPListener.m:123` tells you that it is crashing on line 123 in ADCIAPListener.m -- which, I'm guessing, is the class you pasted in the question.

Comment: but I have't ADCIAPListener  this class in my source cide

Comment: Well this second stacktrace you posted is all but incomprehensible for me (is it even a stack trace??) But the fact that it showed up, symbolicated, with the file name _and_ line number, combined with the fact that a google search produces _nothing_, indicates that the class is _somewhere_ in your project. Seriously, you cannot expect the community to solve your problem with the minimal amount of information you have provided.